# Unexpected different results from Newton's second law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque

Please don't ban me. I read through Homework-like questions and I know they should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. I hope the question is ok.

I recently came across a mechanic basic problem which I wanted to solve following two different approaches. The odd thing is that the approaches bring different results, so probably there might be some wrong reasoning which I cannot explain. Can anyone explain why results are different?

Here's the figure of the system:

[image]

The question is about getting the friction static coefficient between the plane and the bar.

We know the bar weight $P=980N$, and the angle $\theta=60°$, the system is in equilibrium, and the static friction is at its maximum value.

**Solution 1**
Definition of static friction:
$f_{max} =\mu _{s} N\ \rightarrow \ \mu _{s} =\frac{f}{N}$

Newton's second law, forces perpendicular to the plane
$y:\ N=P\cdot \cos 60°$

Newton's second law, torques relative to the right edge of the bar:
$f\cdot L\sin 60°=P\frac{L}{2} \ \rightarrow \ f=\frac{P}{2\sin 60°}$

Static friction coeff:
$\boxed{\mu _{s} =\frac{1}{2\sin 60° \cos 60°}=1.2}$

**Solution 2**
Definition of static friction:
$f_{max} =\mu _{s} N\ \rightarrow \ \mu _{s} =\frac{f}{N}$

Newton's second law, forces perpendicular to the plane
$y:\ N=P\cdot \cos 60°$

Newton's second law, torques relative to the left edge of the bar:
$T\cdot L\sin 60°=P\cdot \frac{L}{2}\rightarrow T=\frac{P}{2\sin 60°}$

Newton's second law, forces parallel to the plane:
$x:\ f+T=P\sin 60°\rightarrow f=P\sin 60°-T=P\sin60°-\frac{P}{2\sin 60°}$

Static friction coeff:
$\boxed{\mu _{s} =\frac{\sin 60° -\frac{1}{2\sin 60°}}{\cos 60°}=0.6}$

**The solutions for the static friction coeff. are different, in particular solution two is $\frac{1}{2}$ solution 1!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is wrong. When you calculate the torques relative of the right edge of the bar you forgot about the torque of force $N$. The correct equation should be
$$ f\cdot L \sin\theta + N \cdot L\cos\theta = P \frac{L}{2} $$
and then you'd get the result that agrees with the second solution.

Comment: aaargh so simple, that's true!!! couldn't see it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In the section "torques relative to the right edge of the bar:"

The torque from the $N$ should be included...best of luck getting the two ways to match.

Comment: Thanks I can see it now!! Checked the first answer, +1 for your kindness

Comment: If it's any consolation it took a while checking through your methods until it got noticed...

Comment: It evaluates for the same result now. thanks again